# Dynamic Programming (to make exact change using exact number of coins)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I have unlimited 4 types of coins in cent: [1, 5, 25, 50].
How to pick *EXACT* 48 coins to make a exact 1 dollar change?(in any one valid way)

I know how to solve this recursively, but is it possible to solve it using DP? How? Thanks!

Comment: Why shouldn't DP be applicable? Why don't you think that the solvable problem classes of DP don't include this case?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You are right. DP is the right way.

Comment: @naqushab thanks to you! Unfortunately I can only choose one answer.

Comment: To readers: here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/qweszxcj/age4xzk4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution may be the following (Haskell):

```
change d coins | null coins = []
               | d==0 = []
               | d>=coin = coin:change (d-coin) coins           
               | otherwise = change d (tail coins) where
        coin = head coins
```

Note that:

1. Given solution assumes that list of coins is desc sorted
2. Case when given value cannot be changed is not handled - I just did not include checks, just demonstrate the idea
3. Input value to change is in cents

Here are some results:

```
*Main> change 100 [50, 25, 5, 1]
[50,50]
*Main> change 99 [50, 25, 5, 1]
[50,25,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1]
*Main> change 75 [50, 25, 5, 1]
[50,25]
```

If you have limitation on number of coins used in solution:

```
exactChange d coins n
    | d==0 && n==0 = [[]]
    | d>0 && n==0 = []
    | d==0 && n>0 = []
    | null coins = []
    | d>=coin = useFirstCoinSolutions ++ skipFirstCoinSolutions
    | otherwise = skipFirstCoinSolutions where
    coin = head coins
    rest = tail coins
    useFirstCoinSolutions = map (\x->coin:x) $ exactChange (d-coin) coins (n-1)
    skipFirstCoinSolutions = exactChange d rest n
```

This gives the following result:

```
*Main> exactChange 100 [50, 25, 5, 1] 48
[[25,25,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[25,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

So, it gives all possible solutions for change 100 cent with exact 48 coins

Explanation

1. First condition d==0 && n==0 defines that single solution found: we have zero amount to change and zero coins left to include in change;
2. Next three conditions defines that solution can not be found;
3. d>=coin this means that given amount is higher than first coin in set of coins so here we have to options: to proceed solutions search *with first coin* or to proceed *without first coin* of the set
4. For the case when first coin is higher than amount we can only proceed *without using first coin*

Comment: Thanks @Nyavro for your reply! Can I ask since the question limit the coins we using (can only use 48 coins), do we pick valid solution from the total final solution set?

Comment: I've give the solution for exact count of coins

Comment: Thank you Nyavro. I found 3 valid results base on your hint.

Answer (score 1):

Let we want to make `n cents` and we are given an infinite supply of each `S = { S1, S2, S3, .. Sm }` coins.

**Dynamic Programming approach:**

To count total number of solutions we can divide all set solutions into **two sets**

1. Solutions that do not contain `mth coin (or Sm)`.
2. Solutions that contain `at least one Sm`.

Let `count(S[], m, n)` be the function to count the number of solutions, then it can be written as **sum** of `count(S[], m-1, n)` and `count(S[], m, n-Sm)`.

Thus formulated as

```
count(n,m) = count(n, m-1) + count(n- sm, m)
```

With the following base cases:

1. `count(n,m) =1, n=0`, one solution -- we have no money, exactly one way to solve the problem - by choosing no coin change, or, more precisely, to choose coin change of 0
2. `count(n,m) =0, n<0`, no solution -- negative sum of money
3. `count(n,m) =1, n>=1, m<=0`, no solution -- we have money, but no change available

Comment: Thanks @naqushab! But the question limits the total coins number we are using (can only use 48 coins), how to deal with that part?

Comment: It can be restricted too. Just add another variable to keep the count of coin used and at each step if coin is added, increment it. And check if it is less than 48, if so, that is the solution. Otherwise, it isn't.